# html form removing PHP tags

Tags: php, html, forms

I don't know if this is a duplicate, don't know. But, please let me explain. When I try to do this:

```
<form action="page.php?action=create_page" method="get">
```

It redirects to this url:`page.php?title=something&content=something`
The title & content is way it is intended, but it seems to remove `action=create_page`
It is probably a simple fix, but help me out anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't directly pass get variables to a php page from an html form ..pass a hidden input value

example

```
<form action="page.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_page"/>
</form>
```

Comment: 4 minutes late with a duped answer

Comment: well, my page was loaded 4 mins ago :) I couldn't notice the answer ..anyway thanks

Comment: You have JS disabled..? If not, then you should see a "There's a new answer to this question" popup to notify you ;)

Comment: that was on the top of the page..didn't get ma attention

Answer (score 6):

Try the `hidden`field

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_page" />
```

Comment: Make sure to place this AFTER your opening `<form..>` tag.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `name="action"`?

Comment: Yes, it works! I changed it to `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_page" />` THANKS!

Comment: I am going to accept answer in 10 minutes, limit by stackoverflow :)

Comment: This, or change the form method to `POST`.

Comment: @AwesomeGuy you accepted the wrong answer... tsk tsk